# Different behavior for qualified and unqualified name lookup for template

Tags: c++, templates, lookup, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup

How should this code behave? It calls generic function ignoring my overload if I use *qualified* name in `call_read()` function; and it calls overload first and then generic version if I use *unqualified* name. What's the difference? Is it a bug in GCC?

```
#include <iostream>

struct info1 {};
struct info2 {};

template<class T> void read(T& x)
{
   std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template<class T> void call_read(T& x)
{
   ::read(x); // if I replace ::read(x) with read(x) the overload is called
}

void read(info1& x)
{
   std::cout << "overload" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   info1 x;
   info2 y;
   call_read(x);
   call_read(y);
}
```

I also noticed that it works different for fundamental types.
See the code bellow

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct info1 {};
typedef struct info2 {};
typedef int info3;
typedef double info4;

template<class T> void read(T x)
{
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template<class T> void call_read(T x)
{
    read(x);
}

void read(info1 x)
{
    std::cout << "overload" << std::endl;
}
void read(info3 x)
{
    std::cout << "overload" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    call_read(info1());
    call_read(info2());
    call_read(info3());
    call_read(info4());
}
```

It is supposed to call overloaded function twice, but it's not.
See the result here
http://codepad.org/iFOOFD52

Comment: Seems strange! Other question: How come `read(info&)` is called, if it's not visible to `call_read(T&)` ?

Comment: I'm not, it's just for testing purposes. I see that it behaves differently based on that how it is called. That's interesting.

Comment: I think @iammilind is up to something. If you change order and overloaded version of `read` appears before `call_read` it works as expected. I don't know why without `::` it does call overloaded (this seems to be the bug).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're observing is a superposition of *two-phase name lookup* and *argument dependent lookup*.

Let's see what the standard says (C++03). [temp.dep]:

> [...] In an expression of the form:
>
> ```
> postfix-expression ( expression-listopt )
> ```
>
> where the postfix-expression is an identifier, the identifier denotes a dependent name if and only if any of the expressions in the expression-list is a type-dependent expression (14.6.2.2).

That means that in both `read` and `::read`, `read` is a dependent name because `x` is type-dependent. That means that it's resolved at the point of instantiation. Let's see what are the rules for this [temp.dep.candidate]:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, if the function name is an unqualified-id but not a template-id, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that:
>
> — For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations with external linkage from the template **definition context** are found.

Therefore for the `::read` case only functions declared before the template definition are considered. But:

> — For the part of the lookup using **associated namespaces** (3.4.2), only function declarations with external linkage found in either the template **definition context** or the template **instantiation context** are found.

for the unqualified `read` both functions are considered, those visible at template definition and template instantiation.

Comment: I don't think this is true. x is always a dependent name which delays lookup to the 2nd phase. The difference is one syntax disables ADL and the other does not. Don't you agree?

Comment: @sellibitze: I agree. But ADL is unrelated to the question. I pretty sure it's a compiler bug.

Comment: I don't agree with your analysis. It's not a compiler bug. This is intended behaviour.

Comment: Update for C++14: `::read` is no longer considered a *dependent name* (i.e. is looked up in the first phase), however the other text was adjusted to compensate for this; it still holds that only functions looked up via 3.4.2 are also looked up in the instantiation context

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is the expected behaviour. In the first case (::read) you effectivly disable ADL (argument dependent lookup) which restricts name lookup to things that have been declared in the global scope *before* your use of read. If you remove :: ADL will kick which may resolve to functions you declared *after* your function template.

Edit: And since for fundamental types like `int` and `double` there is no ADL, this explains your 2nd observation.

Comment: +1, for your analysis (if it's true). But on the other hand you can also explain why `read(into1&)` becomes visible to `call_read()` ? Because of 2 phase argument lookup ?

Comment: @iammilind: info1 is a class-type. Therefore, it has an associated namespace and therefore ADL kicks in. As I said, ADL is not restricted to find entities that have been declared before their use.

Comment: Thanks! Koenig lookup explains the difference between int and structure.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler will always call the method which match the most your call. Here you call :

```
read(T& x) [with T = info1]
```

Thus the compiler will prefer the overload as it precisely match the call. It in the logic of template specializations, which permits to say that if an overloaded function exists which better match your call, then this one will be used.

For the second part of the question, concerning the difference when using fully-qualified and unqualified names, it comes from the fact that fully-qualified name is not dependent to anything else, and is thus resolved to the first match (here your template declaration).

Comment: What I'm saying is the overload should be called for info3 as well, but it's not. The only difference between these 2 overloads is the type. One is fundamental and the other is not.